# pass array to sort using function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to pass data array that is coming from function to sort.
For example :

```
const DEFAULT_COMPETITORS = [ 'Seamless/Grubhub', 'test'];

DEFAULT_COMPETITORS.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
});
```

Above is working fine. But I want data from function instead of `DEFAULT_COMPETITORS` const. I want like below:

My data is coming in `getAllCompetitors` instead of const.

```
function getAllCompetitors() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/salescrm/getTopCompetitorsList',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('getAllCompetitors data: ',data);
            response(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log('data error: ',data);
        }
    });
 }

getAllCompetitors.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
});
```

Hope you guys got.. could any please help me

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

i hope this will work

```js
function getAllCompetitors() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/salescrm/getTopCompetitorsList',
        type: 'POST',
    });
 }


getAllCompetitors()
      .then(res => {
          // you can sort the data 
          let sortedData = res.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
        }); 
        console.log("sortedData once ajax call made the success",sortedData)
      })
      .fail(err= > console.log(err))
```

Comment: {
  "message": "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '>'",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 29,
  "colno": 17
}

Comment: you need to try the code in your project , because you are using url key as "/salescrm/" so here it will take the root which is " https://stackoverflow.com". just try in your domain so it will take the root domain url

Comment: ho that's why. Thank for the clarification ;)

Comment: happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example:

Over any array you could use the funcion .sort() to sort by default sorting rules or using .sort with a function to use a custom sorting rules provided by you in the method

Default sorting:

```js
var items = ['baa', 'aaa', 'aba',"Caa"];
var sortedItems = items.sort();
console.log(sortedItems);
```

Custom sorting:

```js
var items = ['baa', 'aaa', 'aba','Caa'];
var sortedItems = items.sort(function(item1,item2){
     // Locale text case insensitive compare
     return item1.toLowerCase().localeCompare(item2.toLowerCase());
});
console.log(sortedItems);
```

[Mozilla Sort documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)